# How to use react-testing-library and jest with mocked custom react hook updating?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, react-hooks-testing-library

Look at the following custom hook. The premise is that it updates its state when `query` changes.

```
export function UseCustomHook() {
  const { query } = useRouter()
  const [state, setState] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatedState = helperFunction(query)
    setState(updatedState)
  }, [query])

  return state
}
```

The goal is to mock `useRouter` but then also update it to test specifically "helper function is called n-number of times when query updates n-number of times"

We can mock the module `useRouter` with

```
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter() {
    return {
      route: '/',
      pathname: '',
      query: {...},
      asPath: '',
    }
  },
}))
```

But this simply mocks it as a normal module. I want to mock it as a hook and then update it within the test below

```
describe('useCustomHook', () => {
    it('should call helperFunction when query updates', () => {
        const query = {...}
        jest.spyOn(Router, 'useRouter' as any).mockImplementation(() => ({ query }))
        
        const { result } = renderHook(() => useCustomHook())
        expect(...)  
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jest.mock()` to mock `next/router` module, `useRouter` hook and its return value. After we changed the `query` value, we should call [rerender](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#rerender) function to rerender the custom hook, so that the `useEffect` hook will use the new `query` as its dependency.

Besides, I use `jest.spyOn()` to add spy on `console.count()` method to check  how many times the `effect` function calls.

E.g.

`useCustomHook.ts`:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function useCustomHook() {
  const { query } = useRouter();
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.count('effect');
    setState({ id: query.id });
  }, [query]);

  return state;
}
```

`useCustomHook.test.ts`:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useCustomHook } from './useCustomHook';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { NextRouter } from 'next/dist/next-server/lib/router/router';

jest.mock('next/router');

const useMockRouter = mocked(useRouter);

describe('68660313', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const countSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'count');
    const query1 = ({ query: { id: '1' } } as unknown) as NextRouter;
    const query2 = ({ query: { id: '2' } } as unknown) as NextRouter;

    useMockRouter.mockReturnValue(query1);
    const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useCustomHook());
    expect(result.current).toEqual({ id: '1' });
    useMockRouter.mockReturnValue(query2);
    rerender();
    expect(result.current).toEqual({ id: '2' });
    expect(countSpy).toBeCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68660313/useCustomHook.test.ts (7.664 s)
  68660313
    ✓ should pass (32 ms)

  console.count
    effect: 1

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

  console.count
    effect: 2

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File              | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files         |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 useCustomHook.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.184 s
```

packages' version:

```json
"next": "^11.0.1",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```

Comment: `ts-jest` dropped `mocked` because it was included in jest.

https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockedsource-options